# How to make VSCode use global eslint instead of local eslint

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, eslintrc

I opened my project folder in VSCode, after opening it, I ran npm install.

After that VSCode displayed the confirmation box at the top saying "Click on Allow to use the eslint configured locally in the workspace folder". I clicked Allow.

[image]

But then it started giving unnecessary errors like double quotes should be used instead of single quotes.

How to revert back to global ESlint?

I tried exploring ESLint settings in VSCode but didn't find the appropriate setting. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer, to get this dialog box again, run the following command in command palette

ESLint: Reset Library Decision

Reference: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/1023

Answer (score 0):

You can also click the ESlint button in the tool bar at the bottom right of the window. This should open the dialogue again.

[image: an image of VS Code toolbar]

Answer (score 0):

I use a Vagrant VM, and when `node_modules` is in the directory that's visible to both my local hard drive and the VM, performance takes a significant hit.

From a [tip in this post that no longer exists](http://shyp.github.io/2015/07/13/speed-up-your-javascript-tests.html), when I do the following:

```
mkdir ~/whatever
mv /vagrant/node_modules ~/whatever/
ln -s ~/whatever/node_modules /vagrant/node_modules
```

...I get a significant, multi-second speedup when starting the app.  I guess there's a lot of overhead for reading from within a VM when it's in that shared directory.  When the directory is moved into the VM and not directly accessible from the shared directory, it goes a lot faster.

However, this caused problems for VS Code, since it wanted to use the eslint version that it expected to see in the symlinked `node_modules` ... but it couldn't navigate through the symlink.

My solution was to force VS Code to use the globally-installed eslint on my machine, separate from the VM.  To do that, ensure you have eslint installed globally, then:

1. Quit VS Code
2. Remove the symlink to my node_modules directory, so my node app effectively has no node_modules in its root directory
3. Run "ESLint: Reset Library Execution Decisions" in VS Code (and possibly quit VSCode again)
4. Open VSCode, and click "ESLint" in the bottom - it should now ask to use the globally-installed eslint version
5. Success! The Problems tab has eslint warning and errors.

After that's done, I brought the symlink back, and it's still working as expected.

Hope this helps someone else with this slightly strange VM setup!